# JSON Parser show: Expected WooProductModel.Image but found [line:1, column:2491]

Tags: apex, rest-api, webservices, json

I am trying to parse a JSON response from my own site. All the fields are populating with the exception of images. Not sure what I need to do to get the images data. Any help is much appreciated.

My JSON is:

```
{"products":[{ "id" : "7c0ddc371afea935f81863ddfd9ebc1e813121b2",
        "name" : "Establishment",
        "icon" : "http://xxxxxxx.com/shopping.png",
        "images":[{"id":2245,"title":"test","alt":"test","position":0},{"id":2245,"title":"test","alt":"test","position":0},{"id":2245,"title":"test","alt":"test","position":0}],      
        "place_id" : "ChIJ_bErEeHjt4kRlErHPKNZjAA",
        "price_level" : 2
    },
    {         

        "id" : "7c0ddc371afea935f81863ddfd9ebc1e813121b2",
        "name" : "Establishment",
        "icon" : "http://xxxxxxx.com/shopping.png",
        "images":[{"id":2245,"title":"test","alt":"test","position":0},{"id":2245,"title":"test","alt":"test","position":0},{"id":2245,"title":"test","alt":"test","position":0}],      
        "place_id" : "ChIJ_bErEeHjt4kRlErHPKNZjAA",
        "price_level" : 2
    },
    {         

        "id" : "7c0ddc371afea935f81863ddfd9ebc1e813121b2",
        "name" : "Establishment",
        "icon" : "http://xxxxxxx.com/shopping.png",
        "images":[{"id":2245,"title":"test","alt":"test","position":0},{"id":2245,"title":"test","alt":"test","position":0},{"id":2245,"title":"test","alt":"test","position":0}],      
        "place_id" : "ChIJ_bErEeHjt4kRlErHPKNZjAA",
        "price_level" : 2
    }]}
```

My parser is:

```
List<WooProductModel> productList = new List<WooProductModel>();        
        while (parser.nextToken() != null) {
            if (parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.START_ARRAY) {
                while(parser.nextToken() != null)  {
                    if(parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.START_OBJECT) {                
                        WooProductModel product = (WooProductModel)parser.readValueAs(WooProductModel.class);
                        productList.add(product);
                        System.debug('Data: ' + productList);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

And my classes is:

```
public class WooProductModel {

    public Image images{get;set;}
    public String id{get;set;}
    public String name{get;set;}
    public String icon{get;set;}
    public String place_id{get;set;}
    public String price_level{get;set;}


    public WooProductModel(Image images, String id, String name, String icon, String place_id, String price_level)
    {


        this.images = images;
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.icon = icon;
        this.place_id = place_id;
        this.price_level = price_level;

    }



    public class Image{

        public String id{get;set;}
        public String title{get;set;}
        public String alt{get;set;}
        public String position{get;set;}

        public Image(String id, String title, String alt, String position){

            this.id = id;
            this.title = title;
            this.alt = alt;
            this.position = position;             
        }  

    }

}
```

Comment: One thing is that the images are an array so `public Image images{get;set;}` should be `public Image[] images{get;set;}`.

Comment: thanks for your comment. I have solved the problem. just use list as following:    public List<Image> images{get;set;}

Comment: Yep, arrays and lists are interchangeable in many context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem. just use list as following: public `List<Image> images{get;set;}` rather than `public Image images{get;set;}`